# Why Obj2 does not find function by prototype from Obj1 via Object.Create()

Tags: javascript, html, object, prototypal-inheritance

I am trying to look at inheritance via **Object.create()**. I have created Obj1 and added some properties & Methods in it. Now when I am doing **obj2 = object.create(obj1);**, so all properties and methods must also be coming to it via prototype inheritance. Finally, why on finding **obj2.findAge()** is not giving result? Please, can someone help and rectify it?

```html
<html> 
<head></head> 
<body> 
<script> 
var obj1 = {
    name: "Peter Martin",
    age: 29,
    printName: function(){
        console.log(this.name);
    },
    printAge: function(){
        console.log(this.age);
    }
}
var obj2 = Object.create(obj1);
obj2 = {
    name: "Ronald Jane",
    printName: function(){
        console.log("Hello Dear" + this.name);
    }
}
obj1.printName();
obj1.printAge();
obj2.printName();
obj2.printAge();
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

> What I want to do is use **Object.Create()** to get inhertiance
>   from Obj1 to Obj2 with *Obj2 having some of its own private properties*. Please, help me out get this done in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `Object.create` you have assigned the new object reference into the `obj2`, but after it you have changed the reference again when you did `obj2 =  { ... }`, so you lost the last one. If you want to add additional properties into the object, you can use overridden version of `Object.create` or just add it via `.` and `[]` syntax.

What about `findAge` (You mentioned in the post) I don't see it anywhere

```js
var obj1 = {
    name: "Peter Martin",
    age: 29,
    printName: function(){
        console.log(this.name);
    },
    printAge: function(){
        console.log(this.age);
    }
}
var obj2 = Object.create(obj1, { 
   name: { value: 'Ronald Jane', writable: true},
   printName: { value: function() {
        console.log("Hello Dear " + this.name);
   }}
});
//obj2 = { // Here you change `obj2` to refer another object, so you have lost anything which is related to `Object.create(obj1)`
//    name: "Ronald Jane",
//   printName: function(){
//        console.log("Hello Dear" + this.name);
//    }
//}
obj1.printName();
obj1.printAge();
obj2.printName();
obj2.printAge();
```

Comment: Please, copy and improve the example to show what you are saying. There is no findAge; its printAge()

Comment: See the updated part and look how I have called `Object.create`. Also look at the commented part to understand what is going there